# Javascript and PHP in one file (form handling and XMLHTTPRequest)

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, xmlhttprequest

I am confused about my homework requirements: we need to put JS, HTML and PHP code in the same file xxx.php.

There is a form in the HTML, and once I submit the form, I need to send a request (XMLHTTPRequest) to myPHP.php with the form inputs (using POST to transfer the form data PHP). The PHP file will retrieve the form inputs, reformat it to the syntax of the API and send it to the Google API to get JSON object.

I am a beginner of PHP and JS, and I don't know how to combine them in the same file and do the homework based on the requirements. Like, how to send the JSON object obtained in PHP to Javascript.

Here is framework of my code (myPHP.php):

```html
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // show the result
        function show() {
            var xmlhttpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
           
            var keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
            var post_data = "keyword=" + keyword;

            xmlhttpreq.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    createTable(jsonObj);
                }
            };

            xmlhttpreq.open("POST", "myPHP.php", true);
            xmlhttpreq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttpreq.send(post_data);
        }

        function createTable(object) {
            var out = "xxx";
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = out;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="display"></div>

<form action="myPHP.php" name="myForm" method="POST">
    <b>Keyword </b><input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword">
    <br>
    
    <button type="submit" onclick="show()" name="search">Search</button>
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
    // extract the form data
    $keyword = $_POST["keyword"];

    // geocode the address
    $location = urlencode($location);
    // google map geocode api url
    $url = "xxxxxxxx";
    $res_json = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $res_json;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you realise that everything before `<?php` will also be output in the response to the POST request? Is there a requirement that all the code has to be in one file? It's easily done, you just have to understand how PHP works - so, something like https://pastebin.com/MFGSNrrp is closer to what you want

Comment: That can't be right. Are you sure you have interpreted your homework instructions correctly? That page currently contains a messy mix of inline PHP which looks like it is supposed to contribute to the HTML, and would do if the form posted back to itself (as suggested by the <form> element), but then seems to be consumed via JavaScript XHR instead. Is this part of an evolution of a page from being post-back to "ajax"??

Comment: Now I have tried Jaromanda's solution. However, I could not get the data in JS. It shows that the response status is 0. I don't know where is wrong. I just want to display the obtained data in "display" div, but there is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
    // extract the form data
    $keyword = $_POST["keyword"];

    // geocode the address
    $location = urlencode($location);
    // google map geocode api url
    $url = "xxxxxxxx";
    echo file_get_contents($url);
} else {
    echo '<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // show the result
            function show() {
                var xmlhttpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();

                var keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
                var post_data = "keyword=" + keyword;

                xmlhttpreq.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        createTable(jsonObj);
                    }
                };

                xmlhttpreq.open("POST", "myPHP.php", true);
                xmlhttpreq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttpreq.send(post_data);
            }

            function createTable(object) {
                var out = "xxx";
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = out;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="display">
            <?php echo $result; ?>
        </div>

        <form action="myPHP.php" name="myForm" method="POST">
            <b>Keyword </b><input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword">
            <br>

            <button type="submit" onclick="show()" name="search">Search</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to test in `myPHP.php` if there is some data send. If so, the form already has been display and the browser is sending the form data back. If not, it is the first time the php-page is loaded and you can display the html and javascript.

So:

```
<?php
//test if there is data from the form
if( isset( $_POST['some-form-variable'] ) ){
   // YES
   // process data an display something
}
else{
   // NO DATA
   // display form and javascript
}
```

Comment: I could get the data in php and echo it. However, I could not get the data in JS on the same page. I don't know where is wrong. I just want to display the obtained data in "display" div, but there is nothing.